# When upgrading to mule-module-redis-3.4.0, get BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method...RedisModule.set(...)

Tags: java, spring, mule

We've been using mule-module-redis-3.3.3-SNAPSHOT in production with mule 3.4.2 (standalone EE) for about two years now; works great, thanks!

With mule-module-redis-3.4.0, our project's maven compile is ok (yes, we've refactored our code to use the different parameter signatures in some of the RedisModule methods).

But we have been stymied so far with following error below when running any integration test within the maven build. (Our integration test classes simply extend mule's FunctionalTestCase class.)

The one difference we've noticed for the redis-connector 3.4.0 is the RedisModule.set() method has an @Inject annotation; wondering if there could be some dependency conflict or missing dependency/configuration we might be missing?

> "... Error creating bean with name 'globalredis': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public byte[] org.mule.module.redis.RedisModule.set(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,boolean,java.lang.String,org.mule.api.MuleEvent); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: applicationVersion,mysqlPort,testConversionSendToBillingEnabled (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)"

[I've had good suggestions, without success so far :( on the Mule Community Forum with this issue, so hoping there might be others more involved with the mule redis-connector who are here. Thanks!]

Comment: Since you are an `EE` user, I imagine the best course of action is to open an issue with MuleSoft Professional Support.

Comment: One would have thought, but mule-module-redis is an open source connector, and they don't appear to consider any open-source mule component as within the scope of EE support :(

Comment: Aw, I didn't know that :( Apologies for the suggestion then.